# how to call external JWT API service from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices, vaadin

I have two different micro services with Spring security enabled each.

Micro-Service 1: Authentication Service

This API is used for authentication, will take email and password and return back the JWT token as a response.

Micro Service 2:

This application is a front-end application with Vaadin integrated. This application will call the Authentication Service with email and password and get JWT token as a response,
Later by using the JWT token authenticate the user and navigate to the dashboard.

How to accomplish this task? I have no clue how to achieve this. Help me out, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These steps below can make you accomplish the task: *(let's imagine your authentication API is implemented)*

1. Send a request which has a valid username/password from microservice 2 to the authentication API which is placed in your microservice 1.
2. Get the token and save it in a suitable place on the client-side. (local storage, cookie, etc.)
3. Place the token in your request header.

I should clarify that the steps that I mentioned are useful for a common use case. First, you should make sure about the way your authentication service is implemented. Then, probably these steps can help you figure out your task.

Please feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Frontend microservice also having spring security. So how to call an external auth service with a user name and password from internal service and receive JWT to authenticate. Please share any sample code. I don't have any idea how to configure in front-end service.

Comment: There is a bunch of modules out there. 
Just take a look at this tutorial:
https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-rest-services-from-vaadin14

Actually, as I mentioned, just make a request and get the token and put that in your request header. After that, you can make requests to your backend and It will authenticate you.
And also if you're interested ( and I recommend you ) take a look at this series of tutorials, also if you're interested you can find a lot of examples on youtube, just search spring security tutorial.